# Cannot Get Data From Firebase Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem in retrieving data from Firestore. Usually, it works just fine with the code I use, but now I can't read the data from node.js (write from flutter is fine). Tried to console the size result but it returns 0. I don't know if it's related, but the document I have in `user` is looking gray-ish when usually it's black.

[image]

This is my code for retrieving the data.

```
 var database = db.collection('user').get();
    database.then(user => {
        console.log(user.size);
        user.forEach( subcollection => {
            db.collection('user').doc(subcollection.id).collection('pasien').get()
            .then(
                snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach( (pasien) => {
                        if(pasien.data().no_rm == noRm) {
                            console.log(pasien.data());
              
                        }
            
                    })
                }
            )
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know if it's related, but the document I have in user looking grayish when usually it's black.

That is happening because that document doesn't exist. That document doesn't exist because you didn't create it. What you did do, was to create a sub-collection called "pasien" under a document that never existed in the first place. In other words, you have just reserved an ID for a document in the "user" collection and then create a sub-collection under it.

One thing to remember, in Cloud Firestore documents, and sub-collections don't work the way filesystem files and directories usually work in an operating sytem. If you create a sub-collection under a document, it doesn't implicitly create any parent documents. Sub-collections are not tied in any way to a parent document.

If you want to correct that, you have to write at least a property that can hold a value inside *1* document.